# EditText cursor not displayed when overriding onDraw

Tags: textview, android

I have overrided onDraw in a CustomEditText for syntax highlighting purposes and will try drawing with canvas colors instead of spans (too slow). Since the super.onDraw() is not called the cursor is no longer visible. Is it possible to display the cursor?

Comment: Could you past a short version of your code hilighting the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to draw the screen with the default renderer and then overdraw with the appropiate color. The trick is to call super.onDraw mid method. For info I am using the library libhighlight.so from 920-Text-Editor-master. The code still needs work but I am happy with the result.

```
   Highlight highlighter = new Highlight(); 

    @Override
    public void onDraw(final Canvas canvas)
    {
        int currentLine = getLayout().getLineForOffset(getSelectionStart());    
        int firstVisibleLineNumber = getLayout().getLineForVertical(getScrollY());
        int lastVisibleLineNumber = getLayout().getLineForVertical(getScrollY() + getHeight());
        int charWidth = (int) getPaint().measureText("8");

        for (int line = firstVisibleLineNumber; line < lastVisibleLineNumber; line++)
        {
            if (line == currentLine)
            {
                Rect r = new Rect();
                getLineBounds(line, r);
                canvas.drawRect(r, bgndPaint);
            }

            canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(line + 1),
                            5,
                            getLineBounds(line, null),
                            paintNumbers);
        }


        canvas.save();
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();

        if (showSyntax == true)
        {
            int ret[] = highlighter.parse(getText().toString(), "/storage/emulated/0/projects/myIde/assets/html.conf");
            int spanQty = ret.length;
            if (spanQty < 1 || spanQty % 3.0F != 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            int styleQty = getText().toString().length();
            int[] style = new int[styleQty];
            for (int a = 0; a < styleQty;++a)
                style[a] = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < spanQty; i++)
            {
                int group = ret[i];
                int start = ret[++i];
                int end   = ret[++i];

                int color = textColor;

                switch (group)
                {
                    case Highlight.GROUP_TAG_ID:
                        color = colorKeyword;
                        break;

                    case Highlight.GROUP_STRING_ID:
                        color = colorString;
                        break;

                    case Highlight.GROUP_KEYWORD_ID:
                        break;

                    case Highlight.GROUP_FUNCTION_ID:
                        break;

                    case Highlight.GROUP_COMMENT_ID:
                        color = colorComments;
                        break;

                    case Highlight.GROUP_ATTR_NAME_ID:
                        color = colorColor1;
                        break;

                    default:
                        continue;
                }

                for (int c = start; c < end; ++c)
                {
                    style[c] = color;
                }
            }


            for (int line = firstVisibleLineNumber; line < lastVisibleLineNumber; line++)
            {
                int start = getLayout().getLineStart(line);
                int end = getLayout().getLineEnd(line);

                String text = getText().toString().substring(start, end);

                for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); ++i)
                {
                    String c = text.substring(i, i + 1);

                    if (style[start + i] != 0)
                    {
                        getPaint().setColor(style[start + i]);
                        canvas.drawText(c, getPaddingLeft() + (i * charWidth), getLineBounds(line, null), getPaint());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```